# remove previously added and() clause from Where com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select.Where

Tags: cassandra, cql

```
for (int i=0; i<mycolumns.length; i++)
{
   where.and(QueryBuilder.eq(COLNAME, mycolumns[i]));
   //how to remove the above and() call 
}
```

In every iteration of the loop, I want to execute the query and then substitute the value in next loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  I am guessing that you are trying to update multiple rows sharing a primary key, updating 1 row at a time?

Unfortunately this isn't possible since when you call `where.and` you are adding data to the `Where` object and it is returning you a reference to the same Where object.

In short, `Where` is not immutable and neither is the Statement it belongs to, so you won't get a new copy every time you call it, rather you get an updated version of the Where object.

What you could do is generate your Statement again (whether it be `QueryBuilder.update`,`delete`, or insert) in the loop like:

```java
for (int i=0; i<mycolumns.length; i++) {
    Statement stmt = QueryBuilder.update("tableName").where(eq("key", 1)).and(QueryBuilder.eq(COLNAME, mycolumns[i]));
    session.execute(stmt);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've a search query. I've 3 filter criteria, out of that values for 2 are fixed. The last one has multiple values, so I wanted to use same Select statement for different values of the last criteria.
However, the design of the table is already fixed. So, I can't include this last column as part of primary key in which case I could have used IN criteria for all the values of the last parameter.